# Why is my type always coming up as greater than types that come after it?

Tags: types, ocaml

I'm using types in ocaml for a homework assignment and everything works except my type for card values is always causing the integer cards to be scored higher than the face cards despite them being named after.

I thought any type names you put afterwards go in ascending order of greater value? So why is `Simple of int` always greater than the other types?

I know if I put all the values in like

```
type value = Two | Three... | King | Ace
```

that it works but the assignment requires `Simple of int` to be used for the numeric cards.

```
type value = Simple of int | Jack | Queen | King | Ace

Simple 9 > Jack //should be false but is true
Queen > Jack    //should be true and is true
```

Any `Simple of int` should always be less than Jack less than Queen etc. But it seems every `Simple of int` is always bigger than even Ace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally better to define your own comparison function rather than rely on the built-in polymorphic comparison (than depends on the internal memory representation of values). For instance

```
 let (<) x y = match x, y with
 | Simple n, Simple m -> n < m
 | Simple _, _
 | Jack, ( Queen | King | Ace )
 | Queen, ( King | Ace )
 | King, Ace -> true
 | _ -> false
```

Or you can project to a pair of integers

```
 let num = function
 | Simple n -> 0, n
 | Jack -> 1, 0
 | Queen -> 1, 1
 | King -> 1, 2
 | Ace -> 1, 3
```

then define `<` as

```
let (<) x y = num x < num y
```

In order to not shadow the polymorphic comparison, it might be more pratical to put the definition of this custom `(<)` operator inside a submodule, for instance `Infix` and then use it with the local open syntax: `Infix.( x < y )`.

Going back to your initial question, the polymorphic comparison function considers that variant constructors with arguments are greater than constructors without arguments. In other words, if you define

```
   type t = A | B of int | C | D of int
```

the ordering of constructor is `A < C < B < D`. Notably, this definition yields the usual lexicographic order when applied to list. Indeed, lists are essentially defined as

```
type 'a list = 
| [] 
| (::) of 'a * 'a list
```

Then, the ordering `[] < (::)` implies that for any elements `x` and list `q`: `[] < a :: q`

Answer (score 0):

The Simple constructor has a payload and the other constructors do not.  The Ocaml reference manual says of the structural ordering functions such as operator (>) that "These functions coincide with the usual orderings over integers, characters, strings, byte sequences and floating-point numbers, and extend them to a total ordering over all types. The ordering is compatible with ( = )"

So constructors of the same variant type have a total ordering for the purposes of these functions (so that, amongst other matters, for the same arguments operators (=) and (>) will never both evaluate to true), but not necessarily the ordering you would regard as "usual".

One approach is to write a function which pattern matches on the variant and returns a numerical value according to your own wanted ordering, which you can then compare with operator (>).